# External Display not displaying full OSD function tech said solution is HDMI Adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I would like to start off saying I have 0 tech knowledge and this staying at home period has forced me to learn alot!

So recently I bought a new 4k monitor to upgrade my work at home experience.  Previously, an employee at a store helped my set up my Macbook Air (13inch 2017) to an external display monitor via a cable that one end connects to thunderbolt and the other to DP.  Everything worked good.

Then I bought this new monitor that has more options such as blue screen filter, change contrast etc etc (https://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/152620.pdf).  Following what I had done before I connected the two but discovered I am missing the full display option to change this blue light filter and others.  Google didn't give me an answer so I called the tech department of the store and they said this (https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/insignia-insignia-mini-displayport-to-hdmi-adapter-ns-pd94592-c-ns-pd94592-c/10294299) is the magic solution to everything?

Is this true?  I know next to nothing about DP and HDMI and my question is as I only have 1 thunderbold if I buy this adapter does it mean there is no need then for my current thunderbolt to DP cable?

If what the store employee said is true would someone be so kind to link/explain why this would solve my problem, and if not what is the solution to my problem.

Thank you and have a great day :)

Comment: It seems unlikely. In fact the OSD should work when the monitor is not plugged into anything but power. And to be clear here, you are saying that the full OSD menu as shown on page 3-1 is not displaying or not displaying as shown in the illustration? **Also** the place to go for support on this monitor is not where you bought it, rather to the manufacturer, which would be my suggestion before investing more $$ in dubious solutions.

Comment: Hi Steve!  So yes the OSD menu is displaying but not fully displayed in 3-1.  For example I am able to see the Scenery Mode Racing Mode etc etc options that can change my screen color, but there is no left column where I can adjust the blue light filters.

Comment: Then @Allan is on the right track with some good suggestions. I would call ASUS monitor tech support and see if they can help you. B&H Photo & Video is a good place to get good deals on cameras and computers, but for tech support... well the only time I would talk to retailer tech support would be when that was the only way I could return a product. And I've done support in an environment like that. Retailers have to support thousands of products. They are not likely to be an expert on many, if any at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Your cable has nothing to do with the features of the monitor.**   What the store employee told you was utter nonsense.

It simply can’t influence the OSD functionality of the monitor as there’s no logic in a cable that will enable it.  What does influence the OSD is the “mode” that the display is in and that’s dependent on how you have things configured.

In fact, speaking of configurations, the (cable) configuration you had previously, going from mini DisplayPort to Display port (mDP to DP) was better than going from mDP to HDMI as there’s no conversion of the signal.  You’ll get a more stable and reliable connection.

That aside, the monitor’s features are dependent on what “mode” you have it in.

For instance on page 3-2 it states the following:

> - In the Racing Mode, the Saturation, SkinTone, Sharpness, and ASCR functions are not user-configurable.
> - In the sRGB, the Saturation, Color Temp., SkinTone, Sharpness, Brightness, Contrast and ASCR functions are not user-configurable.

Then on page 3-3 specifically about the Blue Light Filter it states

> When Blue Light Filter is activated,the default settings of Racing Mode will be automatically imported.

Based on what you’re describing, that “blue light filter” may be one of the options that get disabled when selecting a certain mode.

Comment: Hi Allan!  Thank you for explaining.  Good thing I didn't buy it then!  However, for blue light filter it should exist in the user mode but I dont see it either.  Do you think its a monitor issue then?

Comment: Definitely.  The OSD is handled by the firmware in the monitor.  If it's not showing, there could be an issue with the monitor - either the firmware is bad or the "blue filter" isn't working.

Comment: Wow and this is a $400 monitor too!  Returned!  Will be shopping for a new one!

Comment: If you want a really, really good 4K monitor, go with the Dell UltraSharp series.  As for the blue fliter gizmo - the [CBC did an expose on why they're a gimmick](https://www.cbc.ca/news/business/marketplace-cheat-sheet-1.5370393).